# What does "Avoid overwriting the input tensor" mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have been studying from Francois Chollet's book, Deep Learning with python, and there is an operation which he always keeps repeating in some of his functions.

```
x = x.copy()
```

And the book says it is done to, **"Avoid overwriting the input tensor"**.

I will post an example code here where he uses this statement.

```
def naive_add(x, y):
    assert len(x.shape) == 2
    assert x.shape == y.shape

    x = x.copy()                         #Avoid overwriting the input tensor.
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        for j in range(x.shape[1]):
            x[i, j] += y[i, j]
    return x
```

This is a simple code for element wise addition of two 2D tensors. I understood the code, but I want to understand the significance of the line `x=x.copy` in this function.

Comment: Because the author wants to keep original x unchanged. Numpy arrays are passed by reference

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get the point. Why assign it again to the same variable `x` and then perform addition? Could you please elaborate if possible?

Comment: because variables in Python works a little bit like pointers. So modifying `x` without making a copy will change the content of array passed to `naive_add()` as `x`. You could replace `x = x.copy()` with `z = x.copy()` and replace all following uses of `x` with `z`.